# plotting equations with increasing variables python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, plot

i have been trying to create a function (Pmotion in the code below) that with several parameters gives me real and imaginary parts of the equation(that part is ok)

but in the next step i want to run the function for an increasing variable(in this case time(t) going up in jumps of 0.1 all the way to 2) and be able to plot the all these samples in an  plot of the real part(Up_real in the y axis) and t in the x axis

how can i get to increase while still retaining the possibility of an initial t input?
any help would be amazing

```
 def Pmotion(x,t,A,alpha,f):
        w=2*np.pi*f
        k1 = (w/alpha)
        theta = k1*x-w*t
        Up = k1*A*complex(-np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)) 
        Up_real = Up.real
        Up_imag = Up.imag
        plt.plot([t],[UP_real]) #here i want these to be in the x and y axis
        plt.show() 

    #Pmotion(x=0,t=0,A=1,alpha=6000,f=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, divide your code in small independent blocks (high cohesion) as such create a function with the desired calculation:

```
def Pmotion(x,t,A,alpha,f):
        w=2*np.pi*f
        k1 = (w/alpha)
        theta = k1*x-w*t
        Up = k1*A*complex(-np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)) 
        Up_real = Up.real
        Up_imag = Up.imag
        return Up_real, Up_imag
```

Then you can begin to think of a plotting method. e.g.

```
def plot_Pmotion_t():
t_range = np.arange(0,2,0.1)
reals = [Pmotion(0,t,1,6000,2) for t in t_range]
plt.plot(t_range, reals)
plt.show()
```

You can now freely alter or add inputs to the plot function without changing the Pmotion function.

Note: You are now plotting both real and imaginary values, change it to `reals = [Pmotion(0,t,1,6000,2)[0] for t in t_range]`

to only plot the real part.
Hope this helps!